# Android image drag to rotate at a fixed point on touch

Tags: android, imageview, drag, image-rotation

I am working on imageView that the user can drag this image [image] by one finger touch to rotate , taking the tail of arrow to be the center. When it comes to the implementation, I have found that the image does rotate as expected. Rather than that, the arrow rotates at shrinking the arrow head and stand as down or right direction. It is a weird rotation I have seen so far. Would you please tell me the proper way to calculate the offset of rotating center ?

The below is my code

private ImageView imageView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double tx = event.getX() - imageView.getWidth()/2;
            double ty = event.getY()  - imageView.getHeight()/2;
            double r = Math.atan2(tx, ty);

            int rotation=(int)Math.toDegrees(r);
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 

                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate((float) rotation, 
                        imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
                imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            }//switch       

            return true;

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You create a new Bitmap after any rotation change? Where did you find any inspiration for that?

Comment: Because I have redraw the image, so using bitmap

Comment: Update the Matrix and call setImageMatrix

Comment: I have edited some code above , when it comes to testing, the image does rotate but the center is the middle of imageview (arrow) instead of the tail of arrow. Would you please tell me the way to modify the offset for rotating center?

Comment: I have edited some code above , when it comes to testing, the image does rotate but the center is the middle of imageview (arrow) instead of the tail of arrow. Would you please tell me how to set the center of x and y for the rotation as the edge of the imageview and show all rotation as gauge needles ?

Comment: IF yoi rotate with pivot other than center your image will disappear, is it what you want?

Comment: what if I want the image to appear if rotating with pivot  ?